# Including license for github projects

Tags: git, github

When I am trying to create a repository at github at the end of the page there is an option for adding a license. What does it mean? That means what if I include a license or not?

Again what does any specific license  means like MIT, Apache, GNU etc etc?

Comment: Adding a license just tells users what they need to do to use your software. Have you read any of them?

Answer (score 1):

You have some details [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/licensing-a-repository) it explains how you allow people to use your code, for instance, if they can use it for a **professional usage** if they can include some of your code in a **commercial product** if you offer any maintenance or **guarantees**.

For instance **MIT License**: They can use your code and modify your code, but they need to acknowledge that they re-used your code.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you create any original work, that work is copyrighted and only extremely limited rights are granted to others. If you're creating a project that you want other people to be able to use, you must use a license to grant them legal permission to do things with it. Otherwise, it's a violation of law for them to do simple things like copying it or using it as part of a project they're working on.

GitHub is trying to help you select one of the most common licenses that people use for open source projects. You can also read more at [Choose a License](https://choosealicense.com/), which explains the most common licenses and how to pick one that meets your needs and goals.